# Why I got permission denied when I'm trying to run docker bitnami apache image?

Tags: docker, apache

I try to run this command " sudo docker run --name image bitnami/apache:latest "

And I get error :

**[Wed May 11 08:05:27.530757 2022] [core:error] [pid 1] (13)Permission denied: AH00099: could not create /opt/bitnami/apache/var/run/httpd.pid.UuG4qO
[Wed May 11 08:05:27.530779 2022] [core:error] [pid 1] AH00100: httpd: could not log pid to file /opt/bitnami/apache/var/run/httpd.pid**

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3,
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mount any volume into the container?

Comment: @TonyYip Nope, no volume

Comment: Can you get the output of the image from the command `docker images --digests`?

Comment: It's OK now. I just deleted the image and re create it.
Thanks all

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.